# using linq to fill an array with random numbers

Tags: vb.net

I am very new to linq and would like to do the following. Create an array of 11 elements (that works ok) contains  random number from 20 to 35 without duplicates. The code I have only gives me random number from 0 to 9.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim r As New Random

    'Create an array of exclusive numbers from 0 to 10
    Dim exclusive_numbers() As Integer = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).OrderBy(Function(n) r.Next(20, 35)).ToArray
    For x = 0 To 10
       MsgBox (exclusive_numbers(x).ToString )
    Next
End Sub
```

I would really like to make this work, but I fear it is over my head at this time. Any help, ideas or working code would be appreciated.
thanks
george

Comment: Why do you want an array? One of the things you should do to make linq work best is to only specify that you need an IEnumerable. Array vs List vs other shouldn't matter, as long as you can iterate/loop over it.

Answer (score 5):

```
   Dim r As New Random()
   Dim exclusive_numbers As Integer() = Enumerable.Range(20, 16).OrderBy(Function(n) r.Next).Take(11).ToArray()
```

Will generate 11 random numbers in the range of 20->20+16-1 => 20=>35

The reason yours is giving 0-9 still is because that is what you are specifying the Enumberable Range of numbers to be (start at 0, generate 10 integers, then randomly sort)

@JoelCoehoorn metions below that order by Random.Next() could cause an Exception. Another way to do this would be to order by a Guid.NewGuid().

```
Enumerable.Range(20, 16).OrderBy(Function(t) Guid.NewGuid()).Take(11)
```

Comment: This will _probably_ work, but note that ordering by Random.Next() will sometimes cause an exception. Not every time, but run it often enough and you'll see this.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn really? Never seen that before. I suppose you could order by `Guid.NewGuid` instead? Though not sure if that would suffer the same exceptions?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: I'd be interested to know when it will cause an exception, because this is the approach I also recommend here on StackOverflow (similar questions are being asked often).

Comment: Ordering by Guid.NewGuid can still cause this. And yes, you see this all over the web, but it's _wrong_ all over the web. Working on an answer that explains why and shows how to do it right.

Comment: FWIW, the execption is pretty rare, and at this sample size is hard to produce... but it can happen

Comment: I have to eat my words here. This was a weakness with array.Sort(), List(Of T).Sort(), and several other pre-Linq algorithms, but the implementation in Linq-to-Objects fixes this and already creates this mapping behind the scenes.